# Hartshorne Chapter V Proposition 1.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

This proposition states as follows,[image]

**What confuses me is the last sentence.** Notice that the Lemma 1.3 states as follows.
[image]

We also have the fact that,

1. The pairing  Div $X \times \operatorname{Div} X \rightarrow \mathbf{Z},$ only depends on the linearly equivalence class.
2. If $C$ and $D$ are nonsingular curves meeting transversally, then $C . D=$ $\#(C \cap D),$ the number of points of $C \cap D.$

**So my qusetion is**

**(1)** In the case of Adjunction formula, how to guarantee  there exists   $H\in|C+K|$ such that $H$ meets $C$ transversally?

**(2)** As mentioned in the statement of self-intersection, for a nonsingular curve $C$ on the smooth projective variety, we also have $C^2=\text{deg}\mathcal O_C(C)$.

So, it seems that we always have $C . D=\text{deg}\mathcal O_C(D)$ for any nonsingular irreducible curve $C$? Is it right? Why?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think your question has been answered in the way that Hartshorne wants this to be done, but I would also mention that you can do this kind of thing in a more "fun" geometric way: let $L$ be a hyperplane section hence very ample. For $m >> 0$, $C+K+mL$ is base point free which is enough to ensure the existence of $H_m \in |C+K+mL|$ which is transverse to $C$. Then you can compute $C.(C+K) = C.(C+K+mL) - C.(mL) = C.(C+K+mL) - m(C.L)$, where we can also find a divisor in class $|L|$ that is transverse to $C$ because $L$ is very ample.

Comment: That is a great comment and merits to be an answer as well. @TabesBridges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer (2) in my way (and afterwards how Hartshorne possibly wanted to do it):

**My way:**

In Proposition 1.4 Harthorne shows that we have $C \cdot D = h^0(\mathscr{O}_{C \cap D})$ for all curves $C$ and $D$ not having common irreducible components. Therefore it suffices to show $$\text{deg}(\mathscr{O}_C(D)) = h^0(\mathscr{O}_{C \cap D}).$$ For this we tensor the short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_C(-D) \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_C \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{C \cap D} \rightarrow 0$$
(here we assume that no irreducible component of $C$ is contained in $D$ to get exactness on the left side) with the line bundle $\mathscr{O}_X(D)$ (which is an exact functor) and get the short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_C \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_C(D) \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{C \cap D} \rightarrow 0.$$ Now we have $h^0(\mathscr{O}_{C \cap D}) = \chi(\mathscr{O}_{C \cap D}) = \chi(\mathscr{O}_C(D)) - \chi(\mathscr{O}_C) = \text{deg}(\mathscr{O}_C(D)),$ where the second equality comes from the additivity of the Euler characterstic and the third equality comes from Riemann-Roch for curves.

**Harthorne's way (I guess):**

I guess Hartshorne wants to combine 1.3 and 1.4 in the following way. Due to 1.3 we have that the degree $\text{deg}(\mathscr{O}_C(D))$ counts the intersection points of $C$ and $D$ and by 1.4 we can compute $C \cdot D$ in terms of the local intersection multiplicities. These local intersection multiplicities at some point $p$ are $\geq 1$ if and only if the point $p$ lies in the intersection. Therefore one has the inequality $$\#(C \cap D) \leq \sum_p (C \cdot D)_p,$$ where $p$ runs over all points in the intersection $C \cap D$. If we now can assure that we never have local intersection multiplicity $\geq 2$ by some assumptions on $C$ and $D$, we have the wanted equality. This is the case if we have transversal intersections, which is the assumption Hartshorne states.

Comment: Dear  @TMO, your answer makes everything pretty clear now. However, For your edit, I can't see why "the fact 2" together with Lemma 1.3 can imply my question (2). It seems that we can't always choose two curves from the linearly equivalence class respectively such that they intersect transversally.  For example, the (1,0) type or (0,1) type line in quardic surface, when we discuss the self-intersection.

Comment: Anyway, your answer has totally solved my question (2). As for my question (1), it seems hard to find that $H$.

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: I was quite busy and never responded to your first comment. I somehow thought by "any nonsingular curve" you still wanted to assume the same intersection behaviour with respect to the other curve $D$. That is what caused my confusion and the edit.